# Books to use for iOS App Development

Tags: curriculum-design, swift, app-development, resource-information

I'm exploring iOS App Development as an elective for students, and in perusing Apple's iBooks on the subject, I see two similar books: [App Development with Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/app-development-with-swift/id1219117996?mt=11) and [Intro to App Development with Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/intro-to-app-development-with-swift/id1118575552?mt=11). On the surface they look quite similar.

**Are there significant differences between the two that I should take into account when selecting one for a course?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are both part of Apple's [Everyone Can Code](https://www.apple.com/everyone-can-code/) initiative, and both are appropriate for a high-school and college audience.

The Intro book is intended for non-programmers, and teaches programming fundamentals and Swift syntax, with 90 hours of lessons included.

The non-intro book gets into more complex UI development such as working with table views and navigation, and topics like consuming web APIs, and includes 180 hours of lessons:

[image: course summary comparison]

[App Development with Swift Curriculum Guide](https://images.apple.com/education/docs/App_Development_with_Swift_Curriculum_Guide.pdf) (where I took that screenshot) also shares helpful outlines of the two curricula that can give you a sense of the differences at a glance.

Here is the Overview from that guide explaining the difference:

> The Intro to App Development with Swift and App Development with Swift
>   curricula were designed to teach high school and college students with
>   little or no programming experience how to be app developers, capable
>   of bringing their own ideas to life.
>
> The Intro to App Development with Swift course introduces students to
>   the world of app development and the basics of Swift and Xcode. The
>   course culminates in a final project where they can choose one of two
>   basic iOS apps to build.
>
> App Development with Swift takes students further, whether they’re new
>   to coding or want to expand their skills. If they’re already familiar
>   with Swift, Xcode, and iOS development, they can move through lessons
>   quickly or go straight to the labs, where they’ll build miniprojects
>   and test their code in playgrounds. By the end of the course, they’ll
>   be able to build a fully functioning app of their own design.

The document goes on to further explain the two courses as follows:

> Intro to App Development with Swift
>
> This introductory one-semester course is designed to help students
>   build a solid foundation in programming fundamentals using Swift as
>   the language. Students get practical experience with the tools,
>   techniques, and concepts needed to build a basic iOS app.
>
> App journal activities take students through the app design process,
>   from thinking about the purpose of an app to market research and early
>   user testing. By the end of the course, students will have created a
>   plan for an app they’d like to develop. Even though they might not yet
>   have the skills to build the app, the work they put into the framework
>   will set them up for future development.
>
> App Development with Swift
>
> This two-semester course features 45 lessons, each designed to teach a
>   specific skill related to either Swift or app development. Each type
>   of lesson takes a different approach:
>
> - **Swift lessons.** These lessons focus on specific concepts. The labs for each are presented in playgrounds so that students can
>     experiment with code and see the results immediately. Playground files
>     are provided.
> - **App development lessons.** Focusing on building specific features for iOS apps, these lessons typically take students step by step
>     through a miniproject. The labs help students apply what they learned
>     to a new scenario.

Comment: Welcome to [cseducators.se], Katie.  I hope we hear more from you going forward!

Comment: Is there anything especially good in print form? Especially for an experienced OOP developer.

Comment: @kateiOS Thank you for this response. That guide is _exactly_ the resource I was looking for. I added information to your post to make it more self-contained on the site here. I echo Ben's comment: welcome and hope to see more from you in our CS Ed community!

Answer (score 0):

I took up iOS teaching recently, and the book that am having great results is the **iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide**

https://www.bignerdranch.com/books/ios-programming/

I liked their style which is extremely practical, and although the book itself is huge, it covers the essentials.

I see that the question is already answered, and I am not being paid to recommend this book. Just adding what has helped my students for those who might be looking for a book that is ideal for teaching older (as in already graduated or those who looking to transition from say being an android developer to iOS developer).

Answer (score -1):

I find Ray Wenderlich's web guides to be the best resource for teaching iOS development.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/category/ios

There also exists a considerable number of books authored by the team that go through iOS and various important first and third-party frameworks.

https://store.raywenderlich.com

Comment: Welcome to [cseducators.se]! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//stackoverflow.meta.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.